# Show that if $|z|=2$, $\text{Im}(1-\bar{z}+z^2)\le 7$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $|z|=2$, $|\text{Im}(1-\bar{z}+z^2)|\le 7$.

My attempt:

Let $z=x+yi$, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $|z|^2=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2=x^2+y^2$.

Since $|z|=2$, then $|z|^2=2^2=4$. So $x^2+y^2=4$. Also, $(x-y)^2\ge0$ $\implies x^2+y^2\ge2xy$;

$$xy\le2 $$

So $|y|\le2$ and $|x|\le 2$.

Now,
$$\begin{aligned}
1-\bar{z}+z^2&=1-(x-yi)+(x+yi)^2\\
&=1-x+yi+x^2+2xyi-y^2\\
&=1-x+x^2-y^2+(2xy+y)i
\end{aligned}$$
Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
\ |\text{Im}(1-\bar{z}+z^2)|&=|y+2xy|\\
&\le|y|+|2xy|\\
&\le |y|+|x^2+y^2|\\
&\le2+4=6
\end{aligned}$$
How about the case when it is equal to $7$?

Comment: It's never seven. Maybe the $1$ in the statement of the problem is supposed to be $i$?

Comment: Without checking the algebra in detail, the basic idea is okay. And mathematically, proving that a<=6 is also a proof that a<=7. In the question there is no strict logical reason that it should ever be equal to 7 to prove this. There is a meta logical concern that if this was an exercise, then they might have given you a tight limit. But, it is also possible that they gave you an easy limit to prove, and you did a bit better. I say this all, however, with out checking the details of the algebra.

Comment: The inequality does NOT require that "equals to $7$" actually happens. Being strictly less does satisfy being less or equal. So you're done -- congratulations!

Comment: Thank you. I thought i also need to prove that one.

Comment: You can easily show that ${\rm max} \  \Im(1-\bar z+z^2) ={\rm max}\ [2x(2x+1)\sqrt{4-x^2}]=5.47....$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality:

$$|1 + (-\bar{z}) + z^2 | ≤ |1| + |-\bar{z}| + |z^2| ≤ 1+2+2^2 = 7$$

(think about what happens to $z = 2e^{i \theta}$).

Comment: And, if the modulus is at most seven, then the imaginary part is at most seven.